# TextView is being cut off in CardView?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-cardview

Good Afternoon, I want to build a Card View with information but everytime I try to build it, the last part of the text gets cut of even though there should be space.

XML file:

I have attached an image on what the issue looks like and don't worry all the information in the photo is fake, is there something I am missing from my layouts that is cutting the text a bit earlier than it should be.

Edit:I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the height of the cardview or "dropdown_printer_setting" linearLayout. Try putting wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constraint layout inside of the card view then add in the other views as child elements.

Also why do you have a fixed height for the card view ? try increasing it to fit or wrap_content. the `120sp` you could also try changing it to `dp` as `sp` is usually used for text size

Answer (score 0):

You should try and increase the height of the card view from 120 to at least 150dp and not sp, this should fix your problem

Comment: yes but it still leaves my question unanswered theres a big chunk of cardview that you can't write in

Comment: You can write in it, see your card view is inside LinearLayout, which has a height of 493dp, but the card view has a height of 120sp(should be dp) so the portion which is not able to fit in the height specified by you is cut off, you can resolve it easily by either increasing the height of card view, or making it wrap_content